# I get an error when I create my own header file

Tags: c++, header

I will write the code of the header file and two `.cpp` files I created under the same folder below. And I tried this under Visual Studio, gcc-gnu, and dev c++. I am getting the following error in the file `employe.cpp`:

> expected initializer before '.' token

`employee.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef employee
#define employee
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class employe{
public:
        string name;
        int id;
        int salary;
        void showInfos();
};
#endif
```

`employe.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "employee.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void employe.showInfos(){
    cout<<"Ad:"<<employe.name<<endl<<"Id:"<<employee.id<<endl<<"Salary:"<<employee.salary;
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "employee.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    
    employe.id=21;
    cout<<employe.id;
    
    return 0;
}
```

`main.cpp` errors:

```
expected unqualified-id before '.' token
expected primary-expression before '.' token
```

I meant to create my own header file and use it. But this happened.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You need `::`, not `.` when defining the function.  `void employe.showInfos(){` -> `void employe::showInfos(){`

Comment: now it gives this error : expected primary-expression before '.' token

Comment: ... and then, *inside* the member function definition, just use the `name` and others. No need for the `employee.`.

Comment: On a side note: [*never* use `using namespace std;` in a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) (or at all, if you can help it).

Comment: `employe` is the name of a type, not a variable, so `employe.id = 21;` is not valid. Try something like `employe bob;  bob.id = 21;` Also employee.h doesn't need `#include <iostream>`, but does need `#include <string>`

Comment: ı had to for string define

Comment: Macros should be named in all caps.

Answer (score 1):

`employe.cpp` fails because you are qualifying everything incorrectly.  It needs to look more like this:

```
#include "employee.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void employe::showInfos(){
    cout << "Ad:" << name << endl << "Id:" << id << endl << "Salary:" << salary;
}
```

`main.cpp` fails because none of your struct members are `static` so you can't access any of them on the struct type itself, like you are trying to do. You need to declare an object instance of `employe`, eg:

```
#include "employee.h"

int main(){
    
    employe emp;

    emp.name = "Joe";
    emp.id = 21;
    emp.salary = 12345;
    emp.showInfos();
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/REo4yCe3f)

Comment: it helped a lot thank you but now it gives this erros :   undefined reference to `WinMain'                      and  ıd returned 1 exit status

Comment: @muratkavak works fine for me: https://onlinegdb.com/REo4yCe3f There are plenty of other questions on StackOverflow for that specific error.  It means your project is not configured correctly, so you need to fix it. That has nothing to do with the code shown.

Comment: ım using DevC++ as compiler.  could this be the problem? what do you suggest as compiler ?

Comment: @muratkavak The way one starts with a new toolchain is to write a "HelloWorld" to make sure you can compile something.

Comment: The compiler is not the issue. The linker is.  It can't find the code for the expected entrypoint for the project. This is because the project is configured as a Windows GUI project (entrypoint `WinMain()`), but the code shown is written for a Console project instead (entrypoint `main()`).